# How do I call a method properly?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, pycharm

I am working on a game and have met a problem. I am getting a error when trying to call the `draw_red_team_one()` method but I can't see the reason why.

It says missing 1 required positional argument: `self` so I checked it out and found out that I had to write `RT = red` and then `self.draw_red_team_one()` so I fixed that but I still get the same error.

```
class red:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x_y = [130, 290]
        self.height_width = [10, 3]
        self.red = [255, 0, 0]

    def draw_salt(self, surface, color, x, y, height, width):
        pygame.draw.rect(surface, color, ((x, y), (height, width)))

    def draw_red_team_one(self):
        self.draw_salt(screen, red, x_y[0], x_y[1], height_width[0], height_width[1])
running = True

while running:
    RT = red
    RT.draw_red_team_one()
    pygame.display.flip()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
```

I expect the full program to open a pygame window and print a white horizontal line with a red box on the top left side. The program just throws me a error.

Comment: Try: RT = red()

Comment: Document [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)  suggest to use `CamelCaseNames` for classes - `class Red` and `lower_case_names` for variables in functions - `rt = Red()`. You can see this even in PyGame which has class `pygame.Rect()` and function `pygame.draw.rect()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `RT = red` you assigned the class to RT, but `draw_red_team_one` is an instance method and as such it requires the positional argument `self` as declared in your method. If you call this method on an instance of class `red`, the argument is implicitely passed, so you don't notice it, but if you call it using `red.draw_red_team_one()` you have to pass it yourself, otherwise you get the error message, you mentioned.
To put it in another way:

```
obj.draw_red_team_one()
```

is the same as:

```
red.draw_red_team_one(obj)
```

The second variant is just what Python implicitly does, when the first variant is executed.

But anyways, you will not need to reference the method in the style of `red.draw_red_team_one` very often. You normally only need this, if you have to pass the method as callable somewhere. E.g. if you have a class with a method, that returns some info of the objects and you want to use methods like `map` to get the information for each object in a list. In that case, you would do something like:

```
map(PersonClass.name, list_of_people)
```

Which is the same as (in the sense that both are iterables returning the same elements):

```
[person.name() for person in list_of_people]
```

Btw. I think your code should rather look like this (haven't checked if it runs though):

```
class red:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x_y = [130, 290]
        self.height_width = [10, 3]
        self.red = [255, 0, 0]

    def draw_salt(self, surface, color, x, y, height, width):
        pygame.draw.rect(surface, color, ((x, y), (height, width)))

    def draw_red_team_one(self):
        # you need to add self. to reference the instance variables
        self.draw_salt(screen, self.red, self.x_y[0], self.x_y[1], self.height_width[0], self.height_width[1])

running = True

while running:
    # create an object (this creates an instance and implicitely calls __init__ which performs your initialization code)
    RT = red()
    RT.draw_red_team_one()
    pygame.display.flip()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
```

Comment: thanks a lot, it worked when i wrote RT = red and red.draw_red_team_one(RT)

Comment: Hmm I think you are misusing the class/methods. I also spotted something else that is not correct. It might work at the moment, but your methods have no reference to the object the way you call it.

Comment: ...and by the way, you also never call the `__init__` method, because you don't instantiate objects.